# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (message): Missigng Dlib install path, please specify DLIB_PATH

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, path, dlib

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (message):
Missigng Dlib install path, please specify DLIB_PATH

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVLy0.png)

I installed the dlib library, but it asks me to specify the installation path. I'm curious how to specify how to use the library. The dlib example is executed (the example provided in the installation path is executed). However, when running from an external file, the above error appears. How can I fix it?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(dlib-sample)

set(DLIB_PATH "" CACHE PATH "path to dlib install dir")

if (NOT DLIB_PATH)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Missigng Dlib install path, please specify DLIB_PATH")
else()
  message("Dlib path is ${DLIB_PATH}")
endif()

set(PLOTCPP_PATH "" CACHE PATH "path to poltcpp install dir")

if (NOT PLOTCPP_PATH)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Missigng plotcpp include path, please specify PLOTCPP_PATH")
else()
  message("plotcpp path is ${PLOTCPP_PATH}")
endif()

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set(requiredlibs "cblas")
list(APPEND requiredlibs "lapack")
list(APPEND requiredlibs "stdc++")
list(APPEND requiredlibs "stdc++fs")

find_package(CUDA)
if (CUDA_FOUND)
  list(APPEND requiredlibs ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
  list(APPEND requiredlibs ${CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES})
  list(APPEND requiredlibs ${CUDA_cusolver_LIBRARY})
  list(APPEND requiredlibs ${CUDA_curand_LIBRARY})

  get_filename_component(cudnn_hint_path "${CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES}" PATH)
  find_library(cudnn cudnn
      HINTS ${cudnn_hint_path} ENV CUDNN_LIBRARY_DIR  ENV CUDNN_HOME
      PATHS /usr/local /usr/local/cuda ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH
      PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib x64
      )
  message("CUDNN found ${cudnn}")
  list(APPEND requiredlibs ${cudnn})
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++17 -msse3 -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -O0")

include_directories(${DLIB_PATH}/include)
include_directories(${PLOTCPP_PATH})

link_directories(${DLIB_PATH}/lib)
link_directories(${DLIB_PATH}/lib64)

add_executable(grid-dlib "grid-dlib.cc")
target_link_libraries(grid-dlib optimized dlib debug dlibd)
target_link_libraries(grid-dlib  ${requiredlibs})
```

Comment: Upload your CmakeList.txt ,also prefer txt logs rather than images

Comment: Have you installed DLIB?

Comment: yes I installed DLIB. I attached cmakefile code

Comment: So you need to pass the installation path of the dlib via `DLIB_PATH` parameter. If you call `cmake` from the command line, the add `-DDLIB_PATH=<..>` option to it.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered.
When I used the'alias' command to specify the installation path, it resolved. I think we should see the cmake file properly now.

Comment: The thing about cache variables is that the variable keeps the first assigned value. The command line option is certainly the earliest possible assignment, but if it suits your needs better you could simply add `set(DLIB_PATH "<your value goes here>" CACHE PATH "path to dlib install dir")` before using `add_subdirectory` to add the `CMakeLists.txt` file posted in the question. You could also use `cmake-gui` on the dir after the error occurs to change the cache value and rerun the configuration.